# Cannot convert 'const T*' to 'T*&&'

Tags: c++, c++11

I am facing an error while trying to add a reference of object to vector of pointers:

```
template <class Tpoint, class Tmodel> Tmodel ransac<Tpoint, Tmodel>::perform_fitting(const std::vector<Tpoint>& data){
    std::vector<Tpoint*> also_inliers;
    for (const auto& pnt : data){
        if (fit_point(pnt, may_be_model) <= t){
            also_inliers.push_back(&pnt); //error here
        }
    } // ! for range
}
```

Error message from VS.NET 2013:

> Error 88  error C2664: 'void std::vector>::push_back(cv::Point_ *const &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const cv::Point_ *' to
>   'cv::Point_ *&&'

Comment: You are missing a `const` in the declaration of your `std::vector`. It should be `std::vector<Tpoint const*>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You capture `pnt` as `const auto&`, but you then try to push it into a vector containing non-const pointers. This violates const-correctness.

Either change `also_inliers` to `std::vector<const Tpoint*>` if you aren't going to be modifying those pointee objects or capture by `auto&` if you need the modification.